# Bad geometry when subsurf

Tags: geometry, displacement, subdivision-surface, experimental-features

I use Blender 2.78c in Experimental feature set. In order to use microdisplacement I added subsurf to my object but set everywhere mean crease 1.00 for preserving original shape. But when I do preview render something goes wrong and my honeycomb being deformed. [image: Honeycomb] [image: Settings] [image: Render]

Comment: And you've confirmed that this *only* happens when using experimental microdisplacement? Also, does disabling experimental features resolve the red warning indicator in your SubSurf Modifier?

Comment: Disabling experimental mode resolves the problem. But subsurf red background title disappears when I add 1 subdivision level. Also when I turn subsurf more than five it looks better but it is too much geometry. I would like keep polygons low and keep experimental because I need microdisplacement.

Comment: Honeycomb also divide this square into 2 faces. I was thinking about cutting this faces to smooth geometry but I can't cut them!

Comment: Can you upload the .blend to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: You have different subdivision levels for rendering and viewport, different results are to be expected. You also seem to be using *Subdivision Surface* on meshes with *Booleans* which is a bad idea

Comment: The problem is probably in ngons. They don't subsurf well. Break them into triangles and it should fix it.

Comment: Or better yet, model in quads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cutting faces works well. Ngons were a problem.[image] [image]